# Is there a "comments" FAQ?

Tags: support, comments

I see people put comments all the time with hyperlinks like what we can set up in the question/wiki editor. I'd love to know how to do this as sometimes I wish to post a link in the comment but not take up a lot of space text wise.

I did a cursory search over the FAQ, but it isn't apparent where this would be. And searches over the site only bring up things related to comments on code, databases, etc.

Is there any help for comments like there is for wiki editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Nick's links, [here you go](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

How did I get there? Jcolebrand has one way in his comment. However, it's also the yellow question mark above the question or answer edit box. Hover over it and it says 'markdown editing help'

Comment: Let's tell how you got there ;-) `Ask a Question` -> `formatting help` near the bottom right -> `comment formatting`

Comment: updated with how **I** got there

Comment: See, this is why it's important to explain your answer :p

Comment: This was actually the answer I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Surround the link text with square brackets, and put the link itself in parenthesis immediate after, like this: `[ link text here ]( URL here, starting with http:// )`

Summary of formatting in comments is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24794/169197) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77500/169197).